# Breeds of dogs for therapy

Tags: dogs, introducing-pets, service-animal

I am interested in and have been researching therapy dogs. I was wondering which breed of dogs make the best therapy dog and why?

Comment: If say you have to be more specific regarding which kind of therapy. Like someone fearing did it something else?

Comment: @Mario a "Therapy dog" is a dog that helps people (other than its owners) with various needs in various settings. Pet Partners is one of the larger Therapy Dog organizations in America, and there website offers explanations of what is a therapy dog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on what kind of therapy. Best advice is to go to your area's website and explore what dogs they have, pictures, and if there are any adoptable career-change dogs. You can also talk to other people in that field about what breeds are best.

Generally speaking in so broad a sense it can barely be called an answer, these breeds typically dominate most fields for their intelligence, train-ability, and relaxed demeanor:

- Golden retriever
- Labrador
- German Shepard

Once you start talking about a more specific field, you'll start to see more breeds, but generally I feel these three are in just about every field.

Answer (score 0):

Cavalier king charles spaniels are often used for therapy dogs to work with children, the elderly, and people with special needs.

They are small, playful, loving, and totally non-aggressive. These characteristics make them ideal for working with the young and the vulnerable.